# Allow registered users and anonymous users to add node with Password - "Password node"

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I've just installed version 7.x-1.x-dev of the protected node module on a drupal 7 site. As administrator, i can manage averything as desired. That mean can set password on node. But my problem is: i want all other users including anonymous and registered users to be able to add a node and set a password on their own. Maybe i'm just missing a detail, but i counld not find any whay to do this in permission without allowing the user to bypass password. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

For adding password for Anonymous User, you have to give them permission of editing and adding any node, and in permission section, you have to set permissions:

```
Access protected node password form
Edit any protected node password
Edit <CONTENT TYPE> password
```

Comment: Thank's it works. I was affraid that by anabling the Edit any protected node password, the users could access every node protected with a password. Actually he can not. Many thanks.